# How to have conditional product attributes in Odoo 13

Tags: attributes, odoo, product, odoo-13

Scenario:

How to create a conditional product attribute in Odoo?

I have a product like:

Product: Pipe 
Attributes: Size, Weight, Thickness

If I select Pipe,
I get option to choose(product variants): Sizes (10' ft, 11' ft.....20'ft) and Thickness (0.5mm, 0.8mm ........ 5mm)
now, this should directly show weight :

If size: 10' ft, Thickness: 0.5 mm 
then weight should be populated as 5 kg

Comment: Can you show where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Are you stuck in adding 2 variants to a product and can't find the weight field in inventory tab?

Comment: No, I m able to add 2 variants. But I wanted to know if it is possible to have conditional variant